# Wait for Async ajax to complete before moving onto other code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked, probably, a million times, but for the life of me I cannot get anything to work.

I have a UI wizard control that on the "changed" event validates the model. If the model is not valid, it doe not allow the user to move forward in the wizard. I have tired using the $.when().done() feature in jquery, but my code still passes through before making sure the model is valid. The reason for calling an async ajax request is I do not want the UI to lock up so I can show some sort of progress indicator. I had set the async property to false, but my UI indicator would never show up. Here is an example of what my code is doing:

```
//the change event that is called when the user clicks 'next' on the wizard:

wizard.on('change', function (e, data) {
      var isValid =  $.validate({
                            "Model": [The_UI_MODEL],
                            "Url": [URL_To_Server_Validation],
                            "Async": true, //tells ajax request to send as async
                        });
      //Tells the wizard not to move 'next' if the request comes back as not valid
      if (data.direction === 'next' && !isValid) {

           e.preventDefault();
        }
}
```

//I am using the $.extend method for JQuery to create a function that will validate any model in my system.

```
validate: function(options) {

            //Clear any previous validation errors
            $.clearValidations();

            var data = $.postJson(options);

            //the result is getting returned before the $.postJson(options) finishes
            return data.Success; 
        }
```

//I created my own method that extends the $.ajax method so I could do other things before /after a request:

```
postJson: function(options){
...other code for my application
//This is where I want the ajax request to happen and once done return the data coming back
//This is what I have tried, but it is not doing what I thought.

$.when(function(){
      return $.ajax({
                url: options.Url,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                async: options.Async,
                timeout: options.Timeout,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(options.Model),
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                   ...do stuff if ajax errors out
                },
                success: function (data) {

                },


           });

}).done(function(response){
       //looks like i get back the responseText of the request. which is fine, but other posts i have read stated i should be getting back the request itself
...other UI stuff
return response;
})



}
```

Comment: write a function which does your actions and place a call to that function in the success `success: function (data) { ... }` ...

Comment: @KarelG, the change event fires first, then then the validate. Since the ajax request is async the $.validate function is called immediately run. The 'var isValid' is always false

Answer (score 0):

KarelG is absolutely right. You need to refactor your code and do your valdiation check within the success callback of the `ajax` request.

Something like this...

```
wizard.on('change', function (e, data) {

    $.ajax({
        url: [URL_To_Server_Validation],
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"Model": [The_UI_MODEL]},
        success: function (response) {

            //Tells the wizard not to move 'next' if the request comes back as not valid
            if(!response & data.direction === 'next')
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        }

    });


});
```

Comment: This does not work, cause the 'e.preventDefault();' fires after the success. So, the wizard still moves forward since this is an async call. Pretty much what I was running into above.

Comment: Why dont you just evaluate it before you do the change then? Is it valid...yes..run the wizard change function

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to write asynchronous code as if it were synchronous. An asynchronous call such as your $.validate() will return immediately without a result and continue on to the rest of your code. Anything you want to happen when the validate call finishes must be done in a callback function passed to it.

You can use [jQuery promises](http://danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/03/22/an-introduction-to-jquery-deferred-slash-promise/) (when, then, done, etc.) or another library such as [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to help manage the control flow.

Also, this isn't particularly useful now since there's little to no browser support for it yet, but the `yield` operator plus a library such as [Task.js](http://taskjs.org/) will eventually let us write asynchronous code as if it were synchronous.

Comment: As you can see in my code, I tried the promises. That did not work for me.

Comment: My main point was about your trying to return a value from an asynchronous call. Conditionally calling e.preventDefault() from the change event handler will not work, because e.preventDefault() must be called during the execution of the event handler, but $.validate() will not have a result until some time after the handler is finished running. Instead, you could always call e.preventDefault() so that the UI never navigates to the next page automatically, then in the callback to your validation function, navigate forward if the data is valid.